# Why do google apps do not work? Any clue in logcat?

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play-services, genymotion

This question is a part of 17 day long (and going) on effort to make google apps work on Genymotion emulator. Until now I have tried every thing I could think of. I have tried everything I could find on stack overflow. Yet google apps do not work.
Every time i get "Unfortunately Google Play services has stopped" or "Google Plays services keeps stopping." It is not possible to add an account, to run play market, browser does not work. In short emulator is not usable.
Also, through my other questions I have received not single one confirmation that actually is possible to install google apps on genymotion emulator.
I have looked through logcat to find any clue what is wrong. But... it offers no useful information. Perhaps somebody else could spot what is wrong.
I am pasting the last part of may logcat.

EDIT (with additional info)

- Genymotion version: 2.8.1

  I have tried both, with included Oracle VM Virtual box and separate instalation of latest VM Virtual box
- android version:

  5.1, 6.0, 7.0, Custom phone device and also some tries with Nexus 6P emulated device and also some others
- Version of open gapps:

  pico, nano, micro, mini, fuul, stock for above android versions. Also i tried that for various releases between 2nd and 17th of February.

I took the x86 build of gapps.
END OF EDIT

This is the last part of my logcat.

```
    02-18 06:01:00.418 F/DEBUG   ( 1811):     #56 pc 006770ee  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+414)
    02-18 06:01:00.418 F/DEBUG   ( 1811):     #57 pc 000fa821  /system/lib/libart.so (artMterpAsmInstructionStart+14497)
    02-18 06:01:00.418 F/DEBUG   ( 1811):     #58 pc 002e3628  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+488)
    02-18 06:01:00.418 F/DEBUG   ( 1811):     #59 pc 002eae70  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+192)
    02-18 06:01:00.418 F/DEBUG   ( 1811):     #60 pc 0031194b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+587)
    02-18 06:01:00.418 F/DEBUG   ( 1811):     #61 pc 0067542f  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+719)
    02-18 06:01:00.418 F/DEBUG   ( 1811):     #62 pc 000fa6a1  /system/lib/libart.so (artMterpAsmInstructionStart+14113)
    02-18 06:01:00.418 F/DEBUG   ( 1811):     #63 pc 002e3628  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+488)
    02-18 06:01:00.446 I/InputReader(  749): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
    02-18 06:01:00.456 I/InputReader(  749): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
    02-18 06:01:00.466 D/CarrierSvcBindHelper(  965): No carrier app for: 0
    02-18 06:01:00.467 W/Searchables(  749): No global search activity found
    02-18 06:01:00.488 D/CarrierSvcBindHelper(  965): No carrier app for: 0
    02-18 06:01:00.493 W/Searchables(  749): No global search activity found
    02-18 06:01:00.813 W/        (  121): debuggerd: resuming target 1791
    02-18 06:01:00.815 I/BootReceiver(  749): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_05 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
    02-18 06:01:00.837 W/BroadcastQueue(  749): Exception when sending broadcast to ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$PersistentTrustedReceiver}
    02-18 06:01:00.837 W/BroadcastQueue(  749): android.os.DeadObjectException
    02-18 06:01:00.837 W/BroadcastQueue(  749):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
    02-18 06:01:00.837 W/BroadcastQueue(  749):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:615)
    02-18 06:01:00.837 W/BroadcastQueue(  749):     at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.scheduleReceiver(ApplicationThreadNative.java:949)
    02-18 06:01:00.837 W/BroadcastQueue(  749):     at com.android.server.am.BroadcastQueue.processCurBroadcastLocked(BroadcastQueue.java:283)
    02-18 06:01:00.837 W/BroadcastQueue(  749):     at com.android.server.am.BroadcastQueue.processNextBroadcast(BroadcastQueue.java:1216)
    02-18 06:01:00.837 W/BroadcastQueue(  749):     at com.android.server.am.BroadcastQueue$BroadcastHandler.handleMessage(BroadcastQueue.java:172)
    02-18 06:01:00.837 W/BroadcastQueue(  749):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    02-18 06:01:00.837 W/BroadcastQueue(  749):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    02-18 06:01:00.837 W/BroadcastQueue(  749):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
    02-18 06:01:00.837 W/BroadcastQueue(  749):     at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
    02-18 06:01:00.837 W/ActivityManager(  749): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.gms/.auth.frp.FrpService in 1000ms
    02-18 06:01:00.843 W/art     ( 1818): Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
    02-18 06:01:00.843 I/Zygote  (  497): Process 1791 exited due to signal (4)
    02-18 06:01:00.848 I/ActivityManager(  749): Start proc 1818:com.google.android.gms.persistent/u0a66 for broadcast com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$PersistentTrustedReceiver
    02-18 06:01:00.848 W/ActivityManager(  749): Spurious death for ProcessRecord{b91e4cc 1818:com.google.android.gms.persistent/u0a66}, curProc for 1791: null
    02-18 06:01:01.940 W/System  ( 1818): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86
    02-18 06:01:01.980 I/LoadedApk( 1818): No resource references to update in package FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
    02-18 06:01:02.032 W/linker  ( 1818): /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk!/lib/x86/libgmscore.so: unused DT entry: type 0x7ffffffd arg 0x754
    02-18 06:01:02.037 W/linker  ( 1818): /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk!/lib/x86/libconscrypt_gmscore_jni.so: unused DT entry: type 0x7ffffffd arg 0x174
    02-18 06:01:02.038 V/JNIHelp ( 1818): Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 242 native methods...
    02-18 06:01:02.057 D/NetworkSecurityConfig( 1818): No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
    02-18 06:01:02.061 I/ProviderInstaller( 1818): Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
    02-18 06:01:02.106 E/ChimeraCfgMgr( 1818): Failed to read module config: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/current_config.pb (No such file or directory)
    02-18 06:01:02.133 E/ChimeraCfgMgr( 1818): Failed to read module config: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/current_config.pb (No such file or directory)
    02-18 06:01:02.152 E/ConfigFileUtils( 1818): Failed to read config file: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/current_fileapks.pb (No such file or directory)
    02-18 06:01:02.161 E/ChimeraCfgMgr( 1818): Failed to read module config: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/current_config.pb (No such file or directory)
    02-18 06:01:02.204 F/libc    ( 1818): Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL), code 2, fault addr 0xe6b4c673 in tid 1818 (.gms.persistent)
    02-18 06:01:02.205 W/        (  121): debuggerd: handling request: pid=1818 uid=10066 gid=10066 tid=1818
    02-18 06:01:02.262 F/DEBUG   ( 1838): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
    02-18 06:01:02.263 F/DEBUG   ( 1838): Build fingerprint: 'Android/vbox86p/vbox86p:7.0/NRD90M/genymo09131924:userdebug/test-keys'
    02-18 06:01:02.263 F/DEBUG   ( 1838): Revision: '0'
    02-18 06:01:02.263 F/DEBUG   ( 1838): ABI: 'x86'
    02-18 06:01:02.263 F/DEBUG   ( 1838): pid: 1818, tid: 1818, name: .gms.persistent  >>> com.google.android.gms.persistent <<<
    02-18 06:01:02.263 F/DEBUG   ( 1838): signal 4 (SIGILL), code 2 (ILL_ILLOPN), fault addr 0xe6b4c673
    02-18 06:01:02.263 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     eax 00000008  ebx e717bb7c  ecx 00000014  edx 00000008
    02-18 06:01:02.263 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     esi 12fe46b0  edi 12d1afc0
    02-18 06:01:02.263 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     xcs 00000023  xds 0000002b  xes 0000002b  xfs 0000006b  xss 0000002b
    02-18 06:01:02.263 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     eip e6b4c679  ebp fffa4388  esp fffa4350  flags 00010283
    02-18 06:01:02.291 D/baseband-sms(  154): index:1/1
    02-18 06:01:02.291 D/baseband-sms(  154): txt:'FQKf.Σ:etΔ#W'
    02-18 06:01:02.293 D/IccSmsInterfaceManager(  965): [IccSmsInterfaceManager] Failed to add GSM cell broadcast subscription for MID range 4371 to 4372 from client com.android.cellbroadcastreceiver
    02-18 06:01:02.294 D/baseband-sms(  154): newsms
    02-18 06:01:02.294 D/baseband-sms(  154): sender:(N/A)
    02-18 06:01:02.294 D/baseband-sms(  154): receiver:122
    02-18 06:01:02.301 D/IccSmsInterfaceManager(  965): [IccSmsInterfaceManager] Calling setGsmBroadcastConfig with 1 configurations
    02-18 06:01:02.326 F/DEBUG   ( 1838): 
    02-18 06:01:02.326 F/DEBUG   ( 1838): backtrace:
    02-18 06:01:02.326 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #00 pc 00107679  /system/lib/libart.so (__memcmp16+1193)
    02-18 06:01:02.326 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #01 pc 0042d586  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art6mirror6String9CompareToEPS1_+70)
    02-18 06:01:02.326 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #02 pc 0044daef  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL16String_compareToEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectS3_+79)
    02-18 06:01:02.326 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #03 pc 0060f04c  /system/framework/x86/boot.oat (offset 0x573000) (java.lang.String.compareTo+136)
    02-18 06:01:02.326 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #04 pc 001083e2  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+338)
    02-18 06:01:02.326 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #05 pc 00111f1d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+237)
    02-18 06:01:02.326 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #06 pc 00319ac6  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter34ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_9ArtMethodEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+294)
    02-18 06:01:02.326 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #07 pc 00311967  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+615)
    02-18 06:01:02.326 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #08 pc 0067542f  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+719)
    02-18 06:01:02.326 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #09 pc 000fa6a1  /system/lib/libart.so (artMterpAsmInstructionStart+14113)
    02-18 06:01:02.326 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #10 pc 002e3628  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+488)
    02-18 06:01:02.326 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #11 pc 002ead80  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter30EnterInterpreterFromEntryPointEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameE+176)
    02-18 06:01:02.326 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #12 pc 00667ad9  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1049)
    02-18 06:01:02.326 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #13 pc 0010e51d  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+77)
    02-18 06:01:02.326 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #14 pc 007b1071  /system/framework/x86/boot.oat (offset 0x573000) (java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending+285)
    02-18 06:01:02.326 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #15 pc 007b5314  /system/framework/x86/boot.oat (offset 0x573000) (java.util.TimSort.sort+288)
    02-18 06:01:02.326 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #16 pc 0071a766  /system/framework/x86/boot.oat (offset 0x573000) (java.util.Arrays.sort+114)
    02-18 06:01:02.326 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #17 pc 001085b2  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+418)
    02-18 06:01:02.326 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #18 pc 00111f69  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+313)
    02-18 06:01:02.326 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #19 pc 00319ac6  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter34ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_9ArtMethodEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+294)
    02-18 06:01:02.326 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #20 pc 00311967  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+615)
    02-18 06:01:02.326 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #21 pc 006770ee  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+414)
    02-18 06:01:02.326 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #22 pc 000fa821  /system/lib/libart.so (artMterpAsmInstructionStart+14497)
    02-18 06:01:02.326 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #23 pc 002e3628  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+488)
    02-18 06:01:02.326 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #24 pc 002ead80  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter30EnterInterpreterFromEntryPointEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameE+176)
    02-18 06:01:02.326 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #25 pc 00667ad9  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1049)
    02-18 06:01:02.326 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #26 pc 0010e51d  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+77)
    02-18 06:01:02.326 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #27 pc 001085b2  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+418)
    02-18 06:01:02.327 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #28 pc 00111f69  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+313)
    02-18 06:01:02.327 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #29 pc 00319ac6  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter34ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_9ArtMethodEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+294)
    02-18 06:01:02.327 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #30 pc 00311967  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+615)
    02-18 06:01:02.327 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #31 pc 006770ee  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+414)
    02-18 06:01:02.327 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #32 pc 000fa821  /system/lib/libart.so (artMterpAsmInstructionStart+14497)
    02-18 06:01:02.327 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #33 pc 002e3628  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+488)
    02-18 06:01:02.327 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #34 pc 002eae70  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+192)
    02-18 06:01:02.327 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #35 pc 0031194b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+587)
    02-18 06:01:02.327 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #36 pc 0067542f  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+719)
    02-18 06:01:02.327 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #37 pc 000fa6a1  /system/lib/libart.so (artMterpAsmInstructionStart+14113)
    02-18 06:01:02.327 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #38 pc 002e3628  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+488)
    02-18 06:01:02.327 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #39 pc 002eae70  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+192)
    02-18 06:01:02.327 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #40 pc 00312b42  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb1ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+450)
    02-18 06:01:02.327 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #41 pc 006776cc  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualRange+716)
    02-18 06:01:02.327 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #42 pc 000fa9a1  /system/lib/libart.so (artMterpAsmInstructionStart+14881)
    02-18 06:01:02.327 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #43 pc 002e3628  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+488)
    02-18 06:01:02.327 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #44 pc 002eae70  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+192)
    02-18 06:01:02.327 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #45 pc 0031194b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+587)
    02-18 06:01:02.327 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #46 pc 006770ee  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+414)
    02-18 06:01:02.327 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #47 pc 000fa821  /system/lib/libart.so (artMterpAsmInstructionStart+14497)
    02-18 06:01:02.327 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #48 pc 002e3628  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+488)
    02-18 06:01:02.327 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #49 pc 002ead80  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter30EnterInterpreterFromEntryPointEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameE+176)
    02-18 06:01:02.327 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #50 pc 00667ad9  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1049)
    02-18 06:01:02.327 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #51 pc 0010e51d  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+77)
    02-18 06:01:02.327 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #52 pc 001085b2  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+418)
    02-18 06:01:02.327 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #53 pc 00111f69  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+313)
    02-18 06:01:02.327 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #54 pc 00319ac6  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter34ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_9ArtMethodEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+294)
    02-18 06:01:02.327 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #55 pc 00311967  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+615)
    02-18 06:01:02.327 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #56 pc 006770ee  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+414)
    02-18 06:01:02.327 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #57 pc 000fa821  /system/lib/libart.so (artMterpAsmInstructionStart+14497)
    02-18 06:01:02.327 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #58 pc 002e3628  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+488)
    02-18 06:01:02.327 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #59 pc 002eae70  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+192)
    02-18 06:01:02.327 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #60 pc 0031194b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+587)
    02-18 06:01:02.327 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #61 pc 0067542f  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+719)
    02-18 06:01:02.327 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #62 pc 000fa6a1  /system/lib/libart.so (artMterpAsmInstructionStart+14113)
    02-18 06:01:02.327 F/DEBUG   ( 1838):     #63 pc 002e3628  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+488)
    02-18 06:01:02.693 W/ActivityManager(  749): Process com.google.android.gms has crashed too many times: killing!
    02-18 06:01:02.693 I/ActivityManager(  749): Killing 1818:com.google.android.gms.persistent/u0a66 (adj 0): crash
    02-18 06:01:02.704 I/BootReceiver(  749): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_06 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
    02-18 06:01:02.704 I/GlobalDismissManager( 1539): no sender configured
    02-18 06:01:02.710 W/BroadcastQueue(  749): Unable to launch app com.google.android.gms/10066 for broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) }: process is bad
    02-18 06:01:02.710 W/BroadcastQueue(  749): Unable to launch app com.google.android.gms/10066 for broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) }: process is bad
    02-18 06:01:02.711 W/BroadcastQueue(  749): Unable to launch app com.google.android.gms/10066 for broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) }: process is bad
    02-18 06:01:02.712 D/AlertService( 1539): Beginning updateAlertNotification
    02-18 06:01:02.714 W/        (  121): debuggerd: resuming target 1818
    02-18 06:01:02.717 D/AlertService( 1539): No fired or scheduled alerts
    02-18 06:01:02.719 D/AlertService( 1539): Scheduling next alarm with AlarmScheduler. sEventReminderReceived: null
    02-18 06:01:02.727 W/BroadcastQueue(  749): Unable to launch app com.google.android.gms/10066 for broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) }: process is bad
    02-18 06:01:02.727 W/BroadcastQueue(  749): Unable to launch app com.google.android.gms/10066 for broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) }: process is bad
    02-18 06:01:02.728 W/BroadcastQueue(  749): Unable to launch app com.google.android.gms/10066 for broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) }: process is bad
    02-18 06:01:02.728 W/BroadcastQueue(  749): Unable to launch app com.google.android.gms/10066 for broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) }: process is bad
    02-18 06:01:02.729 D/AlarmScheduler( 1539): No events found starting within 1 week.
    02-18 06:01:06.835 D/baseband-sms(  154): index:1/1
    02-18 06:01:06.835 D/baseband-sms(  154): txt:'FQKf.Σ:etΔ#W'
    02-18 06:01:06.838 D/baseband-sms(  154): newsms
    02-18 06:01:06.838 D/baseband-sms(  154): sender:(N/A)
    02-18 06:01:06.838 D/baseband-sms(  154): receiver:122
    02-18 06:01:07.683 W/WifiMode(  749): WiredSSID, Invalid SupportedRates!!!
    02-18 06:01:07.683 W/WifiMode(  749): WiredSSID, Invalid SupportedRates!!!
    02-18 06:01:07.684 W/WifiMode(  749): WiredSSID, Invalid SupportedRates!!!
    02-18 06:01:07.806 I/ActivityManager(  749): Waited long enough for: ServiceRecord{8c5e68a u0 com.android.calendar/.alerts.InitAlarmsService}
    02-18 06:01:11.337 D/baseband-sms(  154): index:1/1
    02-18 06:01:11.337 D/baseband-sms(  154): txt:'FQKf.Σ:etΔ#W'
    02-18 06:01:11.339 D/IccSmsInterfaceManager(  965): [IccSmsInterfaceManager] Failed to add GSM cell broadcast subscription for MID range 4373 to 4378 from client com.android.cellbroadcastreceiver
    02-18 06:01:11.373 D/IccSmsInterfaceManager(  965): [IccSmsInterfaceManager] Calling setGsmBroadcastConfig with 1 configurations
    02-18 06:01:11.377 D/IccSmsInterfaceManager(  965): [IccSmsInterfaceManager] Failed to add GSM cell broadcast subscription for MID range 4379 to 4379 from client com.android.cellbroadcastreceiver
    02-18 06:01:11.386 D/IccSmsInterfaceManager(  965): [IccSmsInterfaceManager] Failed to remove GSM cell broadcast subscription for MID range 4380 to 4382 from client com.android.cellbroadcastreceiver
    02-18 06:01:11.396 D/IccSmsInterfaceManager(  965): [IccSmsInterfaceManager] Calling setGsmBroadcastConfig with 1 configurations
    02-18 06:01:11.399 D/IccSmsInterfaceManager(  965): [IccSmsInterfaceManager] Failed to add GSM cell broadcast subscription for MID range 4383 to 4383 from client com.android.cellbroadcastreceiver
    02-18 06:01:11.409 D/IccSmsInterfaceManager(  965): [IccSmsInterfaceManager] Calling setGsmBroadcastConfig with 1 configurations
    02-18 06:01:11.411 D/IccSmsInterfaceManager(  965): [IccSmsInterfaceManager] Failed to add GSM cell broadcast subscription for MID range 4384 to 4385 from client com.android.cellbroadcastreceiver
    02-18 06:01:11.420 D/IccSmsInterfaceManager(  965): [IccSmsInterfaceManager] Calling setGsmBroadcastConfig with 1 configurations
    02-18 06:01:11.422 D/IccSmsInterfaceManager(  965): [IccSmsInterfaceManager] Failed to add GSM cell broadcast subscription for MID range 4386 to 4391 from client com.android.cellbroadcastreceiver
    02-18 06:01:11.433 D/IccSmsInterfaceManager(  965): [IccSmsInterfaceManager] Calling setGsmBroadcastConfig with 1 configurations
    02-18 06:01:11.436 D/IccSmsInterfaceManager(  965): [IccSmsInterfaceManager] Failed to add GSM cell broadcast subscription for MID range 4392 to 4392 from client com.android.cellbroadcastreceiver
    02-18 06:01:11.445 D/IccSmsInterfaceManager(  965): [IccSmsInterfaceManager] Failed to remove GSM cell broadcast subscription for MID range 4393 to 4395 from client com.android.cellbroadcastreceiver
    02-18 06:01:11.452 D/IccSmsInterfaceManager(  965): [IccSmsInterfaceManager] Failed to remove GSM cell broadcast subscription for MID range 50 to 50 from client com.android.cellbroadcastreceiver
    02-18 06:01:22.823 D/InitAlarmsService( 1539): Clearing and rescheduling alarms.
    02-18 06:01:22.855 I/ActivityManager(  749): Killing 1513:com.android.dialer/u0a8 (adj 906): empty #17
    02-18 06:01:22.856 I/ActivityManager(  749): Killing 1255:com.google.android.setupwizard/u0a65 (adj 906): empty #18
    02-18 06:01:22.856 I/ActivityManager(  749): Killing 1240:com.android.keychain/1000 (adj 906): empty #19
    02-18 06:01:27.040 W/AudioTrack(  749): AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client; transfer 4, track 48000 Hz, output 44100 Hz
    02-18 06:01:27.069 W/ActivityManager(  749): Ignoring remove of inactive process: ProcessRecord{b91e4cc 0:com.google.android.gms.persistent/u0a66}
    02-18 06:01:27.122 D/OpenGLRenderer(  749): endAllActiveAnimators on 0xca36ca00 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xca3740c0
    02-18 06:01:27.380 I/WindowManager(  749): Destroying surface Surface(name=Application Error: com.google.android.gms) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2014 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:881 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.destroyOrSaveSurface:2073 com.android.server.wm.WindowSurfacePlacer.performSurfacePlacementInner:429 com.android.server.wm.WindowSurfacePlacer.performSurfacePlacementLoop:232 com.android.server.wm.WindowSurfacePlacer.performSurfacePlacement:180 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$H.handleMessage:8079 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage:102 
    02-18 06:01:27.381 W/AppOps  (  749): Finishing op nesting under-run: uid 1000 pkg android code 24 time=0 duration=0 nesting=0
    02-18 06:01:27.693 W/WifiMode(  749): WiredSSID, Invalid SupportedRates!!!
    02-18 06:01:27.697 W/WifiMode(  749): WiredSSID, Invalid SupportedRates!!!
    02-18 06:01:27.698 W/WifiMode(  749): WiredSSID, Invalid SupportedRates!!!
    02-18 06:01:28.186 W/ActivityManager(  749): Ignoring remove of inactive process: ProcessRecord{f37b92c 0:com.google.android.gms.persistent/u0a66}
    02-18 06:01:28.243 D/OpenGLRenderer(  749): endAllActiveAnimators on 0xcd898c00 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xd1636d20
    02-18 06:01:28.493 I/WindowManager(  749): Destroying surface Surface(name=Application Error: com.google.android.gms) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2014 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:881 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.destroyOrSaveSurface:2073 com.android.server.wm.WindowSurfacePlacer.performSurfacePlacementInner:429 com.android.server.wm.WindowSurfacePlacer.performSurfacePlacementLoop:232 com.android.server.wm.WindowSurfacePlacer.performSurfacePlacement:180 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$H.handleMessage:8079 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage:102 
    02-18 06:01:28.493 W/AppOps  (  749): Finishing op nesting under-run: uid 1000 pkg android code 24 time=0 duration=0 nesting=0
    02-18 06:01:29.076 W/ActivityManager(  749): Ignoring remove of inactive process: ProcessRecord{de23493 0:com.google.android.gms.persistent/u0a66}
    02-18 06:01:29.123 D/OpenGLRenderer(  749): endAllActiveAnimators on 0xcabe7900 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xd1636770
    02-18 06:01:29.133 W/InputMethodManagerService(  749): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@cfd3c18 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@a4e1388
    02-18 06:01:29.345 I/WindowManager(  749): Destroying surface Surface(name=Application Error: com.google.android.gms) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2014 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:881 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.destroyOrSaveSurface:2073 com.android.server.wm.WindowSurfacePlacer.performSurfacePlacementInner:429 com.android.server.wm.WindowSurfacePlacer.performSurfacePlacementLoop:232 com.android.server.wm.WindowSurfacePlacer.performSurfacePlacement:180 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$H.handleMessage:8079 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage:102 
    02-18 06:01:29.345 W/AppOps  (  749): Finishing op nesting under-run: uid 1000 pkg android code 24 time=0 duration=0 nesting=0
```

Comment: 1. Update genymotion 2. Add Google Nexus 5x - 6.0.0 - API23 3. Download ARM Translator v1.1 4. Run Google Nexus 5x 6. Drag and drop ARM Translator v1.1 7. Restart device 8. Download gapps-L-4-21-15 9. Drag and drop 10. Sign in into google play 11. Restart device 12. Download benzo-gapps-M-20151011-signed-chroma-r3 12. Restart device 13.Use apps

Answer (score 1):

This is about the amount of time that all versions of KatKiss using OpenGApps (at least KitKat through Marshmallow) began crashing with ILL_ILLOPC (on ARM).
You have an ILL_ILLOPN (which I'm guessing is the x86 counterpart) here:

`02-18 06:01:02.263 F/DEBUG ( 1838): signal 4 (SIGILL), code 2 (ILL_ILLOPN), fault addr 0xe6b4c673`

On ARM, Google's been adding NEON instructions; I read somewhere that if Google can't detect the processor through /proc/cpuinfo (emulators make me wonder too) they default to assuming it's NEON but I can't find that link now.

Regardless: When Google Play Services silently updates, all their services (and any app that uses them, like DriveSync) across all these custom-ROMs-for-older-CPUs die off. Temporary workarounds (for ARM, x86 may be similar) have consisted of: backing off to an earlier Google Apps (10.0.84), and OpenGApps (Nov 2016), disabling the receiver/update intent, creating stub APKs in /data/app (now confirmed not working; the number just increments) and firewalling - which disables updates altogether. That last one may get you running after backing off/removing GApps.

This is close to the start of the ARM problem...a post from the ROM maintainer...who recommends just not installing GApps:
https://forum.xda-developers.com/eee-pad-transformer/development/rom-t3318496/page84